# How to set default choice in drop down list on first page load using PHP?

Tags: php, default, drop-down-menu

I created a drop down list with the below code, but I want to set a default choice on the first load of the page (i.e., show most recent date, not the first set of options). How can I do this?

```
<?php
$startyear = ""; 
$startmonth = "";
$startday = "";
$endyear = "";
$endmonth = "";
$endday = "";

$year  = range(1998,2012);
$month = range(01,12);
$day   = range(01,31);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
    {
        if(is_numeric($value))
        {
            $$key = $value;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Form stuff here

```
<form name='update' action='' method='POST'>
Start: <select name='startyear'>
    <?php foreach(array_reverse($year) as $y):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $y?>"<?php echo((isset($startyear) && $startyear == $y)?' selected':null)?>><?php echo $y?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
<select name='startmonth'>
    <?php foreach($month as $m): $m = str_pad($m, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);?>
    <option value="<?php echo $m;?>"<?php echo ((isset($startmonth) && $startmonth == $m)?' selected':null)?>><?php echo $m;?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
    <select name='startday'>
    <?php foreach($day as $d): $d = str_pad($d, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);?>
    <option value="<?php echo $d;?>"<?php echo ((isset($startday) && $startday == $d)?' selected':null)?>><?php echo $d;?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
<input type='submit' value='View'/>
</form>
```

Comment: For the love of God get rid of that loop.

Comment: I not too sure .. any wrong with the loop?

Comment: This loop `foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)` is a numeric copy of [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) for $_POST, and in its current state, allows me to set the value of any variable as long as the value is numeric.

Comment: ^Not quite sure what that means, but this page will only be for me, so I don't believe I'll be changing the value of any variable. Now let's get back on topic... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you want ?

```
$cur_day  = date('j');
$cur_mon  = date('n');
$cur_year = date('Y');
```

and then inside the options loop something like this

```
if($y == $cur_year) echo 'selected';
```

then current year will be selected by default, do the same for month and day.

Comment: OP already have this in his code, what he wants is when the form isn't posted yet, how he'd define a default option selected.

Comment: Actually, that date() function was useful. I set my initialization variables to the above.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
    ...
} else {
    // Set your defaults here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your check for being selected is done like this:

```
<?php echo ((isset($startday) && $startday == $d)?' selected':null)?>
```

Simply define your variables with a default value, they are empty!

```
$startyear = ""; 
$startmonth = "";
$startday = "";
$endyear = "";
$endmonth = "";
$endday = "";
```

Comment: @myom: You can set a default value while you initialize them, that's the purpose of initialization.

Comment: I didn't realize I had put that initialization from before haha. Thanks though